# Cannot resolve keyword 'last_activity' into field

Tags: python, django, backend

As title says I was trying to sort a list of posts using the django order_by method and since the field I used was later added to the list (The field was not created inside the model) it failed.

Is there anything I can do about it other than adding the field to the model which is something I really don't wanna do?

Here is the model code

```
class post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=236)
    content = models.TextField()
    post_board = models.ForeignKey(board, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    release_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

The function that adds the extra field:

```
def forumdisplay(request, boardslug=None):

    context = { 'board': None }

    if boardslug:
        context['board'] = board.objects.all().filter(slug=boardslug).first()
        
        if context['board']:
            
            context['posts'] = post.objects.all().filter(post_board=context['board'])
            
            for eachpost in context['posts']:

                eachpost.reply_count = len(reply.objects.all().filter(reply_to=eachpost))
                
                eachpost.last_activity = eachpost.release_date
                
                if eachpost.reply_count:

                    eachpost.last_activity = reply.objects.all().filter(reply_to=eachpost).order_by('release_date').first().release_date

            context['posts'] = context['posts'].order_by('last_activity')   
            alter_posts(context['posts'])
    else:
        pass

    return render(request, "board/forumdisplay.html", context)
```

The error I got:

````
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/forumdisplay/news/
Django Version: 3.0.4
Exception Type: FieldError
Exception Value:    
Cannot resolve keyword 'last_activity' into field. Choices are: author, author_id, content, id, post_board, post_board_id, release_date, reply, title, views```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.
**order_by** that you are trying to use is actually will be translated into SQL command to be executed on database, and while database has no column called **last_activity** so you can't apply this function to it.
what is the problem to add a new column to your DB and make it **nullable**?